# Yii2 Ambiguous error: Expected response code 250 but got code 421

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii2, swiftmailer, mandrill

I'm randomly getting the error when using any endpoint where mail is being sent:

> Expected response code 250 but got code \"421\", with message \"421
>   4.7.0 relay-1.eu-west-1.relay-prod Error: too many errors

Now as I said, this happens randomly with no specific pattern. I'm using **Yii2** with **SwiftMailer** and the mail provider is **Mandrill**

I've been trying to get to why this is happening, but have been going for a couple of days now with no result.

What I've tried so far:

- Firstly, guessed that this is a timout problem, so in config I tried changing the timeout time, but the errors given when the time is decreased considerably, is different from the one I'm getting. So its not a timeout issue.
- Also looked at the mandrill logs, and there are no failures there, so it seems that the requests don't even reach them.
- Since this is a new issue for us, I have also tried reverting all the changes in the code base that have to do with mailing, but nothing changed, I'm still getting the error.

My question is, is there any way to configure swiftmailer so that I get a more informative error? Any help on this, on why this is happening, or how to fix this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You have to make sure that in the model where you trigger `sendMail()` method you have `if` statement with condition if mail was not executed then `throw new RuntimeException("Error while sending the mail");` this will give you at least a point at what time and what params was used to send mail. If that will not help and you will not gonna get any exceptions, then you have look on your server and check the mail logs over there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is details you are looking for: [Swiftmailer only sends 999 emails from BCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697008/swiftmailer-only-sends-999-emails-from-bcc)

If you'll still meet the problem you can use swiftmailer logger to debug process: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/doc/api/2.1/yii-swiftmailer-logger